# subcategory of "nice" maps of topological spaces where each closed inclusion is a cofibration?

Tags: homotopy-theory, model-categories

Is there a subcategory of topological spaces such that each closed inclusion is necessarily a cofibration, and which is good for homotopy theory ?

In general, what are sufficient conditions for a closed inclusion to be a cofibration ?

This is known for cellular maps of CW complexes, but presumably the subcategory of Top consisting of cellular maps of CW complexes is not useful for homotopy theory.
I would assume that maps of manifolds would also have this property.

Here interpret word 'cofibration' in some sense so that there are more of them (Hurewitz cofibrations?)

Comment: You might like to look at the paper "Model categories for o-minimal geometry" by Barton and Commelin (https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.11952).  The category constructed there is not a subcategory of topological spaces, but there is a strong sense in which it serves the same purpose.

Comment: “the subcategory of Top consisting of cellular maps of CW complexes is not useful for homotopy theory”: If you turn CW-complexes into a simplicial category by defining n-simplices of the simplicial mapping space Map(A,B) to be cellular maps of the form Δ^n⨯A→B, then the resulting simplicial category is weakly equivalent to the simplicial category of Kan complexes.  So you recover precisely the usual homotopy theory of spaces.